# JPA Left Join with multiple conditions not giving correct results

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, jpa

I'm trying to write to a Query in JPA,and Query is working fine but result is not correct.

Mapping in User.java

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable( name = "user_roles", 
                joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"), 
                inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();
```

Entity Role.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "roles")
public class Role {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(length = 20)
    private ERole name;
}
```

Enum file

```
public enum ERole {
    USER,
    GUEST,
    ADMIN,
    USER_HANDLER,
    TOURNAMENT_HANDLER,
    CHALLENGE_HANDLER,
    CHAMPIONSHIP_HANDLER
}
```

and Join Query in UserRepository.java

```
@Query("select u.userId from User u LEFT JOIN Role r ON u.id = r.id AND r.name = 'ADMIN' OR r.name = 'USER_HANDLER'")
List<Long> findSubAdmins();
```

Result: I'm printing size of List in console
Expected - 5
Getting - 8 (8 is the total no. of record in join table)

Comment: Looks like it might be a typo u.id = r.id?

Answer (score 0):

```
@Query("select distinct(u.id) from User u INNER JOIN u.roles r ON r.name IN ('ADMIN', 'USER_HANDLER')")
List<Long> findSubAdmins();
```

Comment: Didn't work giving repeated userId.

Comment: Didn't work giving the same result as u.id = r.id.

Comment: Maybe you should add the content of the tables to the question. What's in `users` and `user_roles`? What's the query result? And what do you expect?